# Laravel 5: Open stream exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get sometimes this exception:

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents(/srv/site/storage/framework/cache/3e/8d/3e8d4a387e4a5bfc22e94550f8c986bf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in /srv/site/vendor/compiled.php:6440
```

Does anybody know what can cause this and what could I do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suspect an `php artisan cache:clear` could fix this.
It tries to open a cached file that isn't there.

Comment: Thank you @Gregory, I will try this and see if this error will happen again.